# how to migrate repo from github to gitlab?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

In my case UI import wont work, because github is in our organization private network and gitlab hosted through cloud vm, so need achieve it through commands tried below commands was able to push code, all branches and commits, but PR's where not shown in gitlab. Is there any other commands that i have to execute to get PR in gitlab.

Commands I have used to migrate

```
 git clone --bare clone_url_of_github
 cd .\sample-web-application.git\
 git push --mirror url_of_gitlab
 git lfs fetch origin --all
 git lfs push --all url_of_gitlab
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PR's and comments on the PR's are shared via an API to GitLab so the commands that you have run basically help you to clone a repository from `GitHub` and create a mirror repo on `GitLab` with all the branches so in this approach you cannot get the `MR's/ PR's` in GitLab. Because what you basically have is two different repositories where one is just a mirror of the other.

My recommendation would have been using the import feature which works in such a way that it captures all the data as explained [here](https://about.gitlab.com/community/moving-to-gitlab/) from `GitHub API` and shares it with `GitLab` without losing much of the details so that's basically how `GitLab` is able to capture and store this `PR/MR` information such as comments on the `PR` as well as the other stuff that is listed [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/import/github.html#import-your-github-repository-into-gitlab) on the official `GitLab` migration docs when a `PR` gets imported.

Alternatively, since you don't have permissions to the `GitHub` repo I would recommend you head over to your `GitLab` instance and go to the project repo look for the individual branches and manually create the `MR/PR` using the GUI. With this approach, you will of course lose all of the vital comments from `GitHub` on the PR for that specific branch.